# C++ reversePrint Linked List Recursively

Tags: c++, recursion

Here's the reversePrint function:

```
void SinglyLinkedList::reversePrint(Node* p)
{
    if (p == NULL) {
        return;
    } else {
        reversePrint(p->next);
        cout << p->data << " ";
    }
}
```

(i.e: list = `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4`, print out = `4 3 2 1` )

It will only work if `*p` initially points to what `*head` points to, namely the first node 1. However, `Node* head` is a private member of SinglyLinkedList class thus can't be accessed outside the class. How can I pass `a pointer` that points to `head` from `main` ?

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
int main() {
  SinglyLinkedList *list = new SinglyLinkedList();
  list->addNode(1);
  list->addNode(2);
  list->addNode(3);
  list->addNode(4);

  Node* p = head;  // <---- Xcode says: Use of undeclared identifier 'head'
  list->reversePrint(p);
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to point `*p` to what `*head` points to from inside the `reversePrint` method. But, it disrupted the recursion

```
class SinglyLinkedList {

public:
    // constructor
    SinglyLinkedList();

    // destructor
    ~SinglyLinkedList();

    // public APIs
    void print();
    void addNode(int number);
    void reversePrint(Node* p);

private:
    Node* head;
};
```

Comment: where is 'head' declared or visible in main()? I'm with xcode..

Comment: What is `SinglyLinkedList`? Is it something you have written yourself? You could give it a `const Node* front() const` method that returns the head node.

Comment: I'll add the SinglyLinkedList in just a sec, it's just a `Linked list` data structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Move the member function that works with a `Node*` to the `private` section.
2. Create a `public` member function that does not take any input. Implement it using the `private` member function.

   ```
   void SinglyLinkedList::reversePrint()
   {
      this->reversePrint(this->head);
   }
   ```
3. Call the `public` member function without the `Node*` in calling function.

   ```
   list->reversePrint();
   ```

Comment: coding like a pro ... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can define one public method without parameters and another private method with a parameter that is called from the public method. For example

```
public:
   void reversePrint() const { reversePrint( head ); } 
private:
   void reversePrint(Node* p) const { /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `void SinglyLinkedList::reversePrint(const Node* p) const` private,

and add a public overload `void SinglyLinkedList::reversePrint() const` which calls `reversePrint(head)`.

Alternatively, you may add getter to `head`.